# Is there a way to show crow's feet on schemacrawler diagrams?

Tags: schemacrawler

I am testing out schemacrawler. I like the diagram it generates, but I can't find an option to generate the crow's feet for one-to-many table relationships.

How could I achieve that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: What did you do already? Where did you get stuck? For a high quality question, you should add more details than this.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the issue was a config option.  There are several cardinality options in the config file that determine what to show and not show.